# Error code: SBOX_FATAL_MEMORY_EXCEEDED: React Page using too much memory and crashed at RunTime

Tags: reactjs, react-router, runtime-error, out-of-memory, particles.js

Github link: https://github.com/Bijaypoudel/me
Website Link: https://Bijaypoudel.github.io/me

Doesn't run locally or the deployed one.

It was working fine 2 months ago. It started to crash just last month.

I'm assuming it's because of the dependency version mismatches.
I get following error. I did look up the error code. Couldn't find anything helpful.

Error code: SBOX_FATAL_MEMORY_EXCEEDED
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYrWW.png)

My package.json file:

```
{
  "homepage": "https://Bijaypoudel.github.io/me",
  "name": "me",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.5",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.7.1",
    "emailjs-com": "^2.6.4",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-icons": "^4.2.0",
    "react-particles-js": "^3.4.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.2",
    "react-scroll": "^1.8.1",
    "react-spring": "^8.0.27",
    "sass": "^1.32.8",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.1",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```